# Why won't my SMTP Server send my ASP.NET mail?

Tags: asp.net, iis, email, smtp

I have an ASP.NET program that sends a confirmation email with the following code:

```
 String msgTxt = "My Message";               
 try
 {
      MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
      message.From  = new MailAddress("info@eatrightamerica.com");
      message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailParam));
      message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("NPClients@eatrightamerica.com"));
      message.Subject   = "Your Nutrition Prescription";
      message.Body  = msgTxt;   

      SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
      client.Send(message);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {              
 }
```

The `web.config` file has this:

```
<system.net>  
    <mailSettings>  
       <smtp>  
          <network   
              host="localhost"   
              port="25" />
       </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And my IIS is set to run on Port 25 (I can telnet in and test it, and it sends just fine by telnet).

Can someone direct me somewhere else to look for the problem?

Comment: try debugging or running it without the catch to get the exception details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server you're running your code on set up as an SMTP relay in your email environment? This can be an issue in corporate / enterprise settings in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the SMTP Server and Port via the alternate *SmtpClient* constructors? At least that would tell us the problem isn't the configuration file.

```
int port = 1234;    
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.com", port);
client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the `deliveryMethod` attribute of the smtp element?

```
<system.net>  
    <mailSettings>  
       <smtp deliveryMethod="network">  
          <network   
              host="localhost"   
              port="25" />
       </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually getting an exception? If not, your mail is probably being accepted, but just not sent to the final destination.

Check the mailroot\badmail directory. It might be in there with a possible explanation of the problem (usually DNS resolution).

You can also enable logging for System.Net.Mail. Here is a link I wrote with more info:
http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.10.aspx